# Conditionally render comma in Angular Template

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

On an Angular 7 template I want to display:

```
{{addressLocality}}, {{addressCountry}}
```

So if both are not null this becomes:

```
New York, USA
```

However one of them, or both, might be null which makes no sense for the comma.

Is there a short way to remove the comma when one of them is null?

I was looking at `items.join(", ")` but in this case I have 2 variables and not a list.

Comment: `{{ addressLocality }}{{ addressLocality && ', ' || '' }}{{ addressCountry }}`

Comment: `{{ [addressLocality, addressCountry].join(', ') }}`

Comment: Several options exist, but none are magic, you'll have to code them yourself !

Comment: @trichetriche Your second option still shows the comma when both are null ..

Answer (score 2):

Use a getter :

```
get phrase() {
  return [this.addressLocality, this.addressCountry]
    .filter(val => !!val)
    .join(', ');
}
```

Display it with

```
{{ phrase }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a Pipe that solves the problem (might be useful for someone else):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform  } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'join' })

export class JoinPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform (value: any, character: string = ', '): any {

    if (!Array.isArray(value)) 
      return value;

    return value.filter(x => !!x).join(character);

  }

}
```

And in my question can be used as follows:

```
{{ [addressLocality, addressCountry] | join }}
```

The pipe removes nulls from array by default using `filter(x => !!x)` as @trichetriche suggested.

But this could also be an input of the pipe, e.g., remove or not nulls from array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use as shown below, form an array of the variables, check if they aren't null and then concat with ','.

```
get addressStr(): string {
  return [this.addressLocality, this.addressCountry].filter(Boolean).join(", ");
}
```

and use `{{addressStr}}` in template.

Comment: This gives the error "TypeError: Array.prototype.filter callback must be a function
filter"

Comment: You can't use this syntax, callback can't be written in templates.